# Rails: aliasing the index action in the routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, alias

I have the following route set up. I need to make the index action automatically use the pubmed_search route below.

```
  resources :users do
    resources :publications do
       collection do
         get :pubmed_search
         post :pubmed_list
       end
     end
    end
```

I tried

```
  resources :users do
    resources :publications do
       collection do
         get 'publications', :action => :pubmed_search
         get :pubmed_search
         post :pubmed_list
       end
     end
    end
```

Without luck I could just do a redirect in the index method of the controller but i am sure there is a Rails way to do this and I want to learn.

EDIT:

This works

```
  get "/users/:user_id/publications" => "publications#pubmed_search", :as => "user_publications"
```

But isn't there a better way, using the RESTful resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

get "/users/:user_id/publications" => "publications#pubmed_search", :as => "user_publications"